# Asp.net 3.5 Dynamic Controls

Tags: asp.net, controls

Any body have idea how to put controls dynamically in asp.net 3.5 ?
if any example please provide to me.
another Question : is it possible to create Event for Dynamic Controls ?

Comment: I think you are asking about DynamicControl is data control in ASP.Net 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example (including creating an event) for ASP.NET dynamic controls...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Text = "Click me";
    button.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonClick);

    this.Form.Controls.Add(button);
}

private void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (sender as Button).Text = "You just clicked me!";
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: That's right but i want that the my form will be design by the user
so how many control added dynamically that is not fix.

Comment: @KuldipMCA - I think you need to provide so more detail. If you want your users to add dynamic controls at runtime then maybe web parts might be an option?

Comment: I think what he want is ASP.net 3.5 DynamicControl

Comment: how to get the dyanmic event ??
and how we give serverside validation ??

Answer (score 3):

It is certainly possible, and it's possible to "wire up" a controls events despite it being created dynamically.

See the following links for full information:

[Dynamic Controls in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20210707024005/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx)

[How to: Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx)

[Dynamic ASP.Net Control Creation Using C#.Net](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Dynamic_ASPNet_Control.aspx)

[How To Dynamically Add Controls to a Web Page Video](http://www.asp.net/Learn/ajax-videos/video-286.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.brettb.com/DynamicUserControlsWithLoadControl.asp) is an article that explains how to do it for custom usercontrols.