# User Control not getting instantiated

Tags: asp.net

Master.cs File

```
    ChatUserControl user1 = new ChatUserControl();
                         ChatUserControl user2 = new ChatUserControl();
                         ChatUserControl user3 = new ChatUserControl();
                         divChatUserControlCover.Controls.Add(user1);
                         divChatUserControlCover.Controls.Add(user2);
                         divChatUserControlCover.Controls.Add(user3);

private void BindUserControls()
            {

                                 ChatUserControl user1 = divChatUserControlCover.FindControl("user1") as ChatUserControl;
             }
```

ChatUserControl.cs

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ChatUserControl.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="MetamorphismApp.ChatUserControl" %>

<asp:Timer ID="timer1" runat="server" OnTick="timer1_Tick" Interval="5000">
</asp:Timer>
<div id="divChatWindow" class="clChatWindow">
    <div>
        <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("username") %>' class="divHeader" ID="lblChatFriend"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Image ID="imgFriend" runat="server" CssClass="classFriendImage" />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbClose" runat="server" CommandName="Close" CssClass="lbClose"
            OnClick="lbClose_Click">Close</asp:LinkButton></div>
    <div class="chatText" id="idChatText" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="timer1" EventName="Tick" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSendChat" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rpChatMessages">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="imageForFriend" runat="server" CssClass="clFriendsImage" ImageUrl='<%# "HttpImageHandler.jpg?username=" +  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"fromusername").ToString() %>' />
                        <asp:Label ID="chatMessage" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Message") %>'></asp:Label>
                        <br>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtChatMessage" runat="server" Width="142px" CssClass="clChatMessage" EnableViewState="true"
        TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSendChat" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("username") %>'
        OnClick="btnSendChat_Click">Send</asp:LinkButton>

</div>
```

Master.cs

```
private void BindUserControls()
        {

                             ChatUserControl user1 = divChatUserControlCover.FindControl("user1") as ChatUserControl;
         }
```

I get an error in BindUserControls at user1 control; Object reference not set to instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is that the code that instantiates and puts the controls into the div has not been called.  Make sure that the controls are created even on postback so that further events can be fired / handled.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic controls should be recreated(properly) in each postback. I generally recreate them either in [Init](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/aspnet-ajax/how-to-dynamically-add-controls-to-a-web-page) or [LoadViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287574%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103115/asp-net-3-5-dynamic-controls)

Answer (score 0):

User control cannot be instantiated the way I have done it. There is another way to do it. And that is using Page_LoadControl method.